# Cannot remove double quotations from string in c#

Tags: c#, string, trim

So, I've been trying to remove quotes from a string for over an hour now and I can't seem to get it to work. I'm selecting a folder with a `FolderBrowserDialog`, then I extract the path with `SelectedPath`. Now I'm trying to remove the quotes around the path but seem to be unable to do so.

I've tried the following:

```
string path = folderDlg.SelectedPath.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();
string path = folderDlg.SelectedPath.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();
```

Result:

They both still have the " around the string.

Comment: How are you displaying the result string? Are you certain the quotes aren't just the ones added to indicate the value is a string?

Comment: @JonathonChase The quotes are still showing up in my .ini file. I use `SharpConfig` and output it like this: `section[txtGame.Text].StringValue = path.Replace('"', ' ').Trim();` But this doesn't work either.

Comment: And you are saving your changes after making them with `SaveToFile`?

Comment: Yes, by using `config.SaveToFile("Config.ini");`

Comment: Doesn't `SaveToFile` add the quotes then?

Comment: @SombreroChicken Why would it?

Comment: Are these quotes actually the straight quotes you're using here, such as `"`, instead of the so-called smart quotes, like `“` and `”`? Some operating systems and text editors convert a pair of the former into the latter.

Comment: @JoeSewell I'm talking about the straight ones

Comment: My testing shows this looks like the current behavior of SharpConfig, although the github page makes it look like strings aren't stored with double quotes wrapping them. Reading the StringValue doesn't return the surrounding quotes.

Comment: Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: try saving a new file with your trimmed value in it as "test.txt" or something instead of the SharpConfig method you're currently using.  This will isolate whether it is something in SharpConfig, or your code not properly trimming the value.  If it is the SharpConfig write adding quotes, you'll just need to account for, and strip them, when you read the value back in.  Also, do you use their library to read the save file?  Maybe they already account for them...

Comment: But that keeps me from using their library.

Comment: Are you reading the values from the config from something other that SharpConfig? The quotes shouldn't change the normal expected behavior of the configuration file as they don't get added to the returned value.

Comment: I'm reading it from the `FolderBrowserDialog`

Comment: Looking into it further, it looks like SharpConfig will always wrap with quotes if the value has any spaces in it. You may also need to set `IgnoreInlineComments` to false. The function in play here is on line 548 of https://github.com/cemdervis/SharpConfig/blob/master/SharpConfig/Setting.cs